# Coded UI, how to click on a link using href?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to make a function that will click on some products from the web site that are given only with href attribute, no inner text, value...

for example here is first product I want my function ClickLink to go:

```
<a href="link/100"><img src="something.png" width="145" height="35" border="0"></a>
```

And here is how i tried:

```
void ClickLink(UITestControl parent, string value){

        var link = new HtmlHyperlink(parent);

        link.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.Href, "value");
        Mouse.Click(link);
    }
```

And when I call Click(browser, link/100); nothing happens.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: As far as I rember I found a workaround thought parent-child relationship. @NickW.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the correct href value. You have to pass the href attribute value ("link/100") as the value in search properties.

```
void ClickLink(UITestControl parent, string value){

    var link = new HtmlHyperlink(parent);

    link.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.Href, "link/100");
    Mouse.Click(link);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, it's still the same.

Comment: Can you inspect theelement with coded ui and post the search properties that are listed?

Comment: Well I am new with this so I'm not sure what I have to do. 
However this might help, error:
FailedToPerfomActionOnBlockedControlException: Another control is blocking the control.

Comment: Enable HTML Log output and show us the printscreen if possible

Comment: That error means you have this control behind another control. So the action cannot be fired into the actual control